# Missing Font files in Centos/Linux server (pfb/afm files)

Tags: pdf, printing, fonts, truetype-fonts

I have a pdf file which needs to be printed from a Centos machine to the Windows printer. On executing the print command, the file doesn't print and it throws some error for the missing fonts. Arial and Times New Roman are the missing fonts from the server.

When I see the /usr/share/fonts directory on the server there are files with the format `.pfb` and `.afm` formats inside a directory `/type1`.

On Internet, I find out that to add missing fonts we have to add the `.ttf` files and run the `fc-cache -fv` command.

But I am worried about the different file formats. As on my linux server I find only files with the `.pfb and .afm` format but this `.ttf` is a different format.

1. Will adding the `.ttf` file solve the printing problem?
2. How can I find and add `.pfb and .afm` files for `Arial and Times New Roman`?